# most optimized approach to assign a char* pointer value (who is a struct member) in struct[]

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, char

i am trying to make a collection of structs that some of it's members are a type of string, and as strings are 'expensive' to handle i am trying to maximize performance by using pointers.

i tried my best to learn from tutorials but there are so many different kinds of strings in c++.

what is the fastest way to set `strVal`, if the type of value is  `char*`?

**DataCollection.h**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetContCollection(int CollectionLength,int StrLength, DataContainer** Collection);

typedef struct {
int iValue;
char* strValue;
}DataContainer;
```

**DataCollection.cpp**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetContCollection(int CollectionLength,int StrLength, DataContainer** Collection)
{
    *Collection = (DataContainer*)LocalAlloc(0, CollectionLength * sizeof(DataContainer));  
    // say i need to get a record from database returning a char array
    // and i use current datatype
    *DataContainer CurElement = *Collection;

   // iteration on each element of the collection
   for(int i=0, i< CollectionLength; i++, CurElement++)
   {
       char* x = getsomeValuefromSystemasChar();

       //.... how to assign CurElement->strValue=?
       CurElement->strValue =// kind of Allocation is needed or ....just assign
       //next, do i have to copy value or just assign it ? 
       CurElement->strValue = x or strcpy(dest,source)// if copying must take place which function would be the best?
   }
}
```

what is the correct and **most optimized** way to set `CurElement` ?

Comment: The most expensive part of assigning strings is copying the contents, and this will be pretty much the same no matter how you structure the code. So why not just use `std::string`?

Comment: @Barmar  is that correct when `GetValue()`  is `char*` too by coincidence?

Comment: It depends on the code that returned the value. Is it safe for you to save the pointer, or might the system reuse or free the memory?

Comment: @Barmar if i did not `free` the current thread owns the memory until it is exiting the scope isn't it by design ?

Comment: Please show the _real_ code. This doesn't compile.

Comment: @PblicHieipHagAna It's really hard to answer a generic question like this. It really depends on how `getsomeValuefromSystemasChar()` works. Some APIs return a pointer to a static string, and reuse that string for each call, so you need to make a copy if you want to save it.

Comment: Other APIs allocate the string dynamically, and require the caller to free it or call a function in the library to indicate when they're done with the results.

Comment: If copying must take place, you can use `strdup()` -- `strcpy()` requires you to allocate the space for `dest` first.

Comment: @zenith this is only a pseudo, but still... there must be lines of code that you should omit, the struct definition and method are fine, please explain within a proper answer rather a comment

Comment: @Barmar ok you have a good point, i will update the question to be more specific, as the return value returned by `getsomeValuefromSystemasChar()` is `Char*` but thats all we have, nothing about the way it had been handled within `getsomeValuefromSystemasChar()` is known yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments and edits to the question have rendered a great deal of this answer obsolete. I'm preserving it purely for anybody who might look through the edit history. The part that remains valid is at the end of this answer.

<strike>If, as the question says, all the `char *` in the struct will ever refer to is string literals, then you don't need to allocate memory, or take much in the way of special steps when assigning.</strike>

A string literal has static storage duration, so you can just assign its address to the pointer, and all will be fine. You don't want to allow anybody to accidentally write to the string literal though, so you usually want to use a pointer to `const`:

```
typedef struct {
    int iValue;
    char const * strValue;
} DataContainer;
```

Then when you need to assign, just assign:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetContCollection(int CollectionLength,int StrLength, DataContainer** Collection)
{
    // ...
   CurElement->strValue = "This is a string literal";
}
```

You can count (absolutely) upon string literals having static storage duration, so there's no question this will work. Since you're only assigning a pointer, it'll also be fast.

Unfortunately, it's also somewhat fragile--if somebody assigns something other than a string literal here, it can break very easily.

That brings us to the next question: whether you're really dealing with string literals *at all*. Although you specifically ask about string literals, the demo code you show doesn't look like it's dealing with string literals at all--and if it's not, code like the above will break horribly.

If you have to deal with that,

I'd say just use `std::string`. If you insist on doing this yourself, there's an excellent chance you'll produce something broken, and very little (almost no) chance you'll gain a substantial speed advantage without breaking anything.

Comment: first thanks a lot . " _if somebody assigns something other than a string literal here, it can break very easily_ " <- what if that is not going to happen, as i will make sure only char or some other chars kindes `OLECHAR` or `LPOLESTR` etc' , no other type would be assiged . in that case is it still  that risky ?

Comment: @PblicHieipHagAna: The emphasis here is on *literal*. Just doing a simple assignment depends on the fact that a string *literal* has static storage duration. Most other strings do *not* have static storage duration, which will break this. If you're dealing with `OLECHAR` or `LPOLESTR`, etc., there's almost no chance that you're dealing with string *literals*, in which case this will break.

Comment: " _the demo code you show doesn't look like it's dealing with string literals at all_ " please i have no clue what you refer at this point.

Comment: maybe i have used a `keyword` -> `string literals` i mean `string` / `char` variants

Comment: @PblicHieipHagAna: A string literal is a string that's enclosed in quotes, present in the source code (such as the `"This is a string literal"` in my reply). Although it's possible to return a string literal from a function, I think it's unlikely that `getsomeValuefromSystemasChar()` would return a literal. In this case, the difference is crucial.

Comment: i think i need to take a 'high resolution' lesson on `string`s and `char`s by it self ...

Comment: in response to your last comment A string literal => `var x = "abcd..";`< hard coded, then this is not what i ment , exactly not Literal but a returned value for now i will refer only to `char*` pointer, or `char[]`

Comment: so to sum it all, bottom line we decide return type != `string literal` then result -> _code like the above will break horribly_ ?

Comment: @PblicHieipHagAna: Yes, probably (it's still *possible* you'd be dealing with strings with static storage duration, in which case it would work, but I'd consider it quite unlikely. I've edited accordingly.